# Make HTTP request in cURL in proper way

Tags: php, json, http, curl

I am passing data in Curl as below, it seems I have done something wrong as it is not working.... please guide me how to make the request correctly.

Below is the full code:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://staging.logistics.com/v2/shipments/create';

$data = '
"request_id" : "10",
 "value": "false"
';

$data_string = json_encode(array(
    "customer" => $data
));

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:application/json'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Authorization: Basic ZcnM6ZHV55tbXlLZXk="
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo "$result";
?>
```

I got this HTTP error:

> 415 Problem accessing /v2/shipments/create. Reason: Unsupported Media
>   Type

Comment: Is `ZcnM6ZHV55tbXlLZXk=` your actual value? I would expect that to be a valid base64 encoded string, which that isn't.

Comment: @iainn thanks for reply, means i am putting `ZcnM6ZHV55tbXlLZXk=` in question , but api team send this : `ZGFegtyjhmRlcnM6ZHVtbXlLZXk=` , i did't want to reveal that here, so i posted that, but i am trying with correct value....

Comment: @iainn is there any syntax error here : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Authorization: Basic ZcnM6ZHV55tbXlLZXk="
);`

Comment: " i did't want to reveal that here"...but yet you did...ooops (unless your second version is also deliberately missing something, I guess :-))

Comment: Anyway, "not working" is a useless description of your problem. We already know that...otherwise you wouldn't be asking! What response are you receiving from the remote server when you send the request? The HTTP status code and any error message in the response body would be sensible things to tell us. Then we have a better idea of why the request might be failing.

Comment: we need the HTTP status code from the remote server as well, please. P.S. Is that _your_ PHP which is generating that message, or the remote server?

Comment: @ADyson thanks, i got this `HTTP ERROR 415
Problem accessing /v2/shipments/create. Reason:

    Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: I think your $data_string is unlikely to be formatted the way you expect, and unlikely to be useful JSON. It will be double-encoded i.e. `{"customer":"\r\n\"request_id\" : \"10\",\r\n \"value\": \"false\"\r\n"}` because you're making a JSON-like string in $data and then encoding that as JSON. $data should be an object or array, not a string. Then you encode the whole object to a JSON string. I don't think your problem is due to the Auth header at all. a 415 means the server cannot understand what you placed in the request body (i.e. the JSON)

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b207a96c3449ffa835f62119e31a027cd98357b) of it producing faulty JSON

Comment: @ADyson thanks for suggestion, before i had this : https://pastebin.com/6Pt8MQZT but it gave syntax errors, that i could't able to find....  someone suggested to pass in array like i posted in question.....

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13ee1dd8343966d34bde27dbbed215a369b35ae7) of what you probably need to do instead.

Comment: The syntax error in your pastebin is because that's not how you declare an associative array in PHP - but you can look up the syntax for that anywhere, you shouldn't need me to tell you :-(

Comment: @ADyson thanks, so  i should follow [array as here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13ee1dd8343966d34bde27dbbed215a369b35ae7) , not as [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b207a96c3449ffa835f62119e31a027cd98357b) , right ?

Comment: @ADyson thanks,  i will do changes suggested by you.....

Comment: exactly, yes, try that. And I don't know who told you to write an array like you did it in the pastebin, but they don't know what they are talking about...it would be valid as raw JSON, but not as a PHP syntax.

Comment: P.S. If you still get a 415 error after that, then you should check whether the API actually accepts JSON at all - not all do. Perhaps you'd be required to send in traditional URL-encoded format instead, or maybe XML or something. Always check what's supported before you start. If you're unsure, send me a link to the documentation page and I'll take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182413/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Unsupported Media Type" error is because you are not sending valid JSON. Since you create `$data` as a string, and then `json_encode()` it, you end up with double-encoded data, which the server does not recognise. The code shown in the question will cause `$data_string` to be output as

```
{"customer":"\r\n\"request_id\" : \"10\",\r\n \"value\": \"false\"\r\n"}
```

A usable version of this would be

```
{"customer": { "request_id" : "10", "value": "false" } }
```

To get that, you'd write the code by making a PHP object / array, and then encoding that object:

```
$data = array("request_id" => "10", "value" => "false");

$data_string = json_encode(array(
    "customer" => $data
));
```

[Here's a demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13ee1dd8343966d34bde27dbbed215a369b35ae7) showing the output of the code above.

You could also shorten that code to:

```
$data = array( 
  "customer" => array(
    "request_id" => "10", 
    "value" => "false")
  )
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Your mistake was to confuse the creation of the data in the PHP code with the encoding of it into the textual transmission format (JSON, in this case). Instead you need to create the data in PHP using a (nested) associative arrays and regular arrays in such a way that when you pass that to json_encode(), the output payload is in the correct format required by the API.

Comment: please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182413/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-adyson

Comment: @vickeycolors why? What issue are you facing?

Comment: hi, Is there any link i can follow to "Download  table's  single row details in pdf onclick button using php mysqli" ? image : https://prnt.sc/ldjgj9

Comment: @vickeycolors Possibly...you can use google yourself, I'm sure? But anyway the logic is quite simple: The button must be within a form. The form must include a hidden field with the ID of the database record which the table row is referring to. When the form is submitted to PHP, check the ID which is sent from the browser. Get the record with that ID from the database, add the data into a PDF, send the PDF for download. This is possible either using knowledge you already have, or knowledge you can look up online.

Comment: Thanks again, i already tried with google for some time, but no luck, will try some more time.....

Comment: @vickeycolors ...cont'd: There might not be a specific article following that whole process end-to-end but there will definitely be articles showing you each of those individual steps I mentioned. Plug them all together and you've got your solution. It's always a good idea to break down your requirement into little steps. When you do that, you usually find that each step on its own is something already known and understood, and thus easily researched. That's the trick to successful code design - making some bigger logic created from lots of little pieces you already know about.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the token to the curl option like so

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: ' . $your_token));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Authorization: Basic ZGFpbreewmRlcnM6ZHVtbXlLZXk="
));` but it gave error as `HTTP ERROR 415
Problem accessing /v2/shipments/create. Reason:

    Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: @ADyson did you read the question title??. If you can't provide a solution to his problem, It is better to keep to yourself.

Comment: Yes I did. And then I looked at the actual error message given, and, if you understand HTTP error messages, it is very obvious that the error is entirely unrelated to the title. OP simply made an incorrect assumption. Then, if you look further into the code you can see a mistake which might result in a 415 error. Try reading the comments before posting. You'll see I have suggested a solution, and am awaiting a response.

Comment: And if you're answering the question just based on the title, then that's not a good approach. Look at the reality of the situation and the code instead. People commonly make incorrect assumptions about what their problem is. It's only natural, if you don't understand what's going wrong. That's why you have to look into the situation fully before rushing to answer. You'll see I have now amended the question content to reflect the actual situation better.

Comment: And lastly, you've said "try"...but why? What's your rationale? You didn't say why your solution would be any better. On what basis should we bother to spend our time trying this out? I see no evidence presented to support your suggestion. I note youv'e removed the "Basic"...but what gives you to understand that Basic auth is not being used? And why is concatenating some (unspecified) variable value into the string any better than hard-coding it? What difference would it make? It seems your answer is based on even more unverified assumptions that the original question title.

Comment: Ok mate. keep awaiting a response.

Comment: As you see from the comments we are in discussion about it now. You can follow the discussion if you're interested. Perhaps you can help us out. In the meantime are you intending to answer any of my questions above?

Comment: Nah mate. I'll pass. Have fun helping him out, wish you all the best. Answering your questions would be a pointless exercise. here's one of my favorite quotes from the bible "If you answer a silly question, you are just as silly as the person who asked it. 5 Give a silly answer to a silly question, and the one who asked it will realize that he's not as smart as he thinks." Proverbs 26: 4-5 . and i ain't even a christian

Comment: I think you're not answering my questions because you can't, because your answer to the original question makes no sense, and you seem to dislike people pointing that out. Please be aware it's nothing personal (how could it be, we don't know each other), I'm only interested in the technical qualities of the answer. A mature response would be to look again at the question and try to figure out a better answer based on the evidence. And to discuss and learn from the experience, instead of providing glib quotes from an ancient book of riddles as a way to avoid discussing the actual points at hand

Comment: No problem. I only hope you learned something about a HTTP 415 error. BTW, it's possible to delete answers, if you wish.

Comment: Ahh yes i learnt a ton about the HTTP 415 error, all that knowledge, so empowering. but did you know its possible to stop replying, if you wish. I bet you can't